# Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library

Tags: java, android, file

I have this error when I implement file picker library
here is the **`build.gradle`** file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 30
        buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"
    
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 30
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
    
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.2'
        implementation 'ir.samanjafari.easycountdowntimer:easycountdowntimer:2.5.0'
        //implementation 'com.droidninja:filepicker:2.2.5'
    //    implementation 'com.github.jaiselrahman:FilePicker:1.3.2'
        implementation 'com.nbsp:materialfilepicker:1.9.1'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    }
```

this is the library `implementation 'com.nbsp:materialfilepicker:1.9.1'`

how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library you used supports SDK version 19 as a minimum, whereas your app supports a minimum of 16. That's why it's failed.

You can update your minSdk Version to 19 in this line:

```
minSdkVersion 19
```

Or you can use another library of the same characteristics which supports a minimum 16 SDK